# React Conditional Rendering using switch

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to render a component based on props passed by the parent component, then in the children component i evaluate the props using switch statement. I was unable to get return element based on props.length. I have searching for the way using conditional rendering properly in react, but it seems something in my code goes wrong and i didnt realize it until now.

```
//Countries.tsx
import React from "react";
import ListCountries from "./ListCountries";
import Country from "./Country";

const Countries = ({ data }) => {
  let dataLength = data.length;
  let component = null;
  switch (dataLength) {
    case dataLength === 1:
      component = <Country data={data} />;
      break;
    case dataLength > 1:
      component = <ListCountries data={data} />;
      break;
    case dataLength > 10:
      component = <div>Too many matches, specify another filter</div>;
      break;
    default:
      component = <p>Else statement</p>;
      break;
  }

  return <>{component}</>;
};

export default Countries;
```

````
export default function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(res => {
      setCountries(res.data);
    });
  }, [query]);

  const inputSearchHandler = e => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
    const res = countries.filter(country =>
      country.name
        .toLocaleUpperCase()
        .includes(e.target.value.toLocaleUpperCase())
    );
    setFilteredCountries(res);
  };

  console.log("countries : ", countries);
  console.log("countries length: ", countries.length);
  console.log("filtered : ", filteredCountries);
  console.log("filtered length: ", filteredCountries.length);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchField inputSearchHandler={inputSearchHandler} />
      <Countries data={filteredCountries} />
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Can you explain whats going wrong/ or any error?

Comment: Pardon me, it keeps evaluate to the default on switch statement, so the Countries component always render <p>Else statement</p>. Full in codesandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-conditional-rendering-sccwn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think you will love Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code but I was able to get it to work:

1. the switch statement isn't built for "greater than" / "less than" statements. Usually, switch is used like this:

   ```
    switch(number) {
        case 1: dothis();
        case 2: dothat();
    }
   ```

   there is a workaround, you could do this:

   ```
    switch(true) {
        case number > 1: dothis();
        case number < 1: dothat();
    }
   ```

   but i would stick to `if`, `else if` and `else` statements.
2. You made a small error in this line:

   ```
    case dataLength > 1:
          // do something
    case dataLength > 10:
          // do something else
   ```

   If we assume `dataLength` is 11, it would still execute first case since the condition `dataLength > 1` is true. To fix this, make sure to change the first statement to `case dataLength > 1 && dataLength < 10`
3. I did some minor changes to make the code more readable.

This is the final result:

```
import React from "react";
import ListCountries from "./ListCountries";
import Country from "./Country";

const Countries = ({ data }) => {
  const getComponent = () => {
    let dataLength = data.length;    
      if (dataLength === 1) return <Country data={data} />;
      else if (dataLength > 1 && dataLength < 10) return <ListCountries data={data} />;
      else if (dataLength > 10) return <div>Too many matches, specify another filter</div>;
      else return <p>Else statement</p>;    
  };

  return getComponent();
};

export default Countries;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!, anyway, should i use if-else statement instead of switch if i'd like to render based on greater than / less than?. or using greater than / less than is not suggested in conditional rendering?

Comment: @AchmadWahyu I suggest you don't use greater than / less than in combination with switch. I usually use switch if I have a variable and I want to switch through the possible outcomes (for example if I have a variable that contains either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 I'd use switch case. But to be honest, it doesn't really matter. If else is fine